# Freelan server configuration

Tags: networking, vpn

I have two networks. One has a 192.168.0.xxx IP range; the other 192.168.1.xxx. On the 192.168.0/24 network, I want to host a Freelan VPN server, so that any given client can connect to it from any location, but mainly from the 192.168.1/24 network, so that the client is truly virtually in that network and can communicate with any machine in the network – much like a typical workplace VPN.

I am not seeing any real examples of configuration for a VPN server using Freelan. 
How can I do this?